# Update values in tensor along deeper dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have tensor A of shape MxNxC where M stands for number of examples, N is number of features and C is 3 euler rotation angles. Also i have a tensor B of similar shape, but instead of angles there are coordinates.
What is needed is to convert both of these tensors to one containing affine transformation matrices so its shape would be like MxNx4x4. I dont know how to iterate over these tensors together, I've looked for [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) and [tf.scan](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) but they iterate only with the first dimension. What im looking for is some method to apply function like the one below to all of the elements along the last axes.

```
def f(angles, vector): #dimensions 3 or 3x1
    ...
    return matrix # dimension 4x4
```

Any help would be useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
A_flattened = tf.reshape(A, [-1, 3])# flatten it out
B_flattened = tf.reshape(B, [-1, 3])
AB_flattened = tf.map_fn(convert_to_mat, (A_flattened, B_flattened))# convert_to_mat should return a 4x4 matrix
AB = tf.reshape(AB_flattened, [M, N, 4, 4])
```

this should do the trick!